# How to save MS word (docx) as secure / locked PDF on Mac OS X using macros

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2016

I have a question on how to modify the macros below so that to save PDF as secure (i.e. locked for editing) PDF. This macros works in Word 2011 and 2016 on Mac.

```
Sub SaveActiveDocAsPDF()

On Error Resume Next

Dim saveName As String
saveName = ActiveDocument.FullName
saveName = Left(saveName, Len(saveName) - 5) & ".pdf"

ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=saveName, _
FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never ever use `On Error Resume Next` without a proper error handling. This only hides errors but they still occur, it just makes you blind for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to export a password protected PDF without using 3rd party plugins. This is not supported by Word itself, the [Document.SaveAs2 Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/document-saveas2-method-word?) doesn't evaluate the `Password` parameter when using PDF as file format.

For more information have a look here at the Microsoft Community: [Save password protected PDF file with VBA](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2010/save-password-protected-pdf-file-with-vba/e3b0be70-d7a5-421b-888f-980d35386c40).

But there are several 3rd party softwares that could be used like [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator).